# Is there any way to make a container overflow to the left?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Same as the heading, really. I have two divs, each 50% width. An image might end up in either one and if the right image is too wide it simply overflows right. Perfect. But so does the image on the left. Needless to say this messes up the 50/50 appearance of the two divs.

So -- is there any way to force an overflow to the *LEFT*?

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content_1">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="content_1">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
}
.container > div {
    width: 50%;
}
.container_1 {
    overflow: left /* I know this doesn't exist... yet */
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please? We cannot do that much without your HTML / CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css property `direction:rtl` to force the right-to-left behaviour of text which in the context of overflowing an image gives the impression that it is being overflowed to the left.

**Basic example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image image1"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"/></div>
    <div class="image image2"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.image {
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}
.image1 {
    direction: ltr;
}
.image2 {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

**Demonstration:** http://jsfiddle.net/n5LyR/1/

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up-vote you, but worth mentioning is that I tried this earlier and it didn't work. But having checked out your CodePen I realized that this *DO NOT WORK* with display:table-cell.

Comment: @user3850960 If you add `table-layout:fixed;` it works: http://jsfiddle.net/n5LyR/2/ (on some browsers it may not). However if your only reason for using the table layout is for vertical alignment, which is usually my only reason for doing this, then there are plenty of other ways.

Comment: True, there are, but I needed to create an element that could be re-used in a WYSIWYG environment and some of the hacks that are typically used make it too easy to break (Our CMS is practically pre-historic), but we just dropped support for IE9 so I used FlexBox. All's well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `direction` to show a scrollbar that goes opposite direction  or use `float:right` on content  to hide it on the left side
**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zbkCJ)**

HTML

```
<div class="ovfleft">
  <p> lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="hidetoleft">
  <p> lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:300px;
  margin:3px auto;
  border:solid;
}
.ovfleft {
  direction:rtl;
  overflow:auto;
}
p {
  width:500px;
  direction:ltr;
}
.hidetoleft {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.hidetoleft p {
  float:right;
}
```